# Android sqlite insert issue

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

I'm trying to add data from a csv file to an sqlite database on Android.

My data in csv file looks like this

```
SID,Attended,Serial,Time,Title,Forenames,Last name,Parking,How many people will be in your     party (including yourself)?,Any access requirements?,Access requirements,Timetable
9290,,0000000092906,2014-04-07 18:44:59,Miss,foo1,foo1,,2,No,,fooo
9291,,0000000092907,2014-04-08 18:44:59,Miss,foo2,foo2,,2,No,,fooo
9292,,0000000092908,2014-04-07 18:44:59,Miss,foo3,foo3,,2,No,,fooo
```

I created a DatabaseHelper to import it :

```
public void importFromCSV(String filename) 
{
    //deleteTable();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String next[] = {};

    try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
        reader.readNext();
        for(;;) {
            next = reader.readNext();
            if(next != null) {
                this.addPerson(new Person(Long.parseLong(next[0]),
                        next[1],
                        Long.parseLong(next[2]),
                        next[3],
                        next[4],
                        next[5],
                        next[6],
                        next[7],
                        Integer.parseInt(next[8]),
                        next[9],
                        next[10],
                        next[11]));
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }

}
```

But when I try to do a SELECT on my database, I got an error : CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException : Index 0 requested, with a size of 0.
I did some research and found that this error was because of an empty cursor.

Here is my getPerson function :

```
public Person getPerson(long sid){

    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor = 
            db.query(TABLE_PERSONS, // a. table
            COLUMNS, // b. column names
            " sid = ?", // c. selections 
            new String[] { String.valueOf(sid) }, // d. selections args
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null); // h. limit

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    // 4. build pers object
    Person pers = new Person();

    pers.setSid(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0)));
    pers.setAttended(cursor.getString(1));
    pers.setSerial(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(2)));
    pers.setTime(cursor.getString(3));
    pers.setTitle(cursor.getString(4));
    pers.setForename(cursor.getString(5));
    pers.setLastname(cursor.getString(6));
    pers.setParking(cursor.getString(7));
    pers.setNumberpeople(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));
    pers.setAccessreqornot(cursor.getString(9));
    pers.setAccessreq(cursor.getString(10));
    pers.setTimetable(cursor.getString(11));

    Log.d("getPerson()", pers.toString());

    // 5. return pers
    return pers;
}
```

I think the issue is due to my addPerson function called in importFromCsv().
My log at the beginning of the addPerson function returns me the right thing, but I think the db.insert is not going well. But I don't have any error on this.

My addPerson function :

```
public void addPerson(Person pers){
    Log.d("addPerson", pers.toString());
    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SID, pers.getSid()); 
    values.put(ATTENDED, pers.getAttended());
    values.put(SERIAL, pers.getSerial());
    values.put(TIME, pers.getTime());
    values.put(TITLE, pers.getTitle());
    values.put(FORENAME, pers.getForename());
    values.put(LASTNAME, pers.getLastname());
    values.put(PARKING, pers.getParking());
    values.put(NUMBERPEOPLE, pers.getNumberpeople());
    values.put(ACCESSREQORNOT, pers.getAccessreqornot());
    values.put(ACCESSREQ, pers.getAccessreq());
    values.put(TIMETABLE, pers.getTimetable());

    // 3. insert
    db.insert(TABLE_PERSONS, // table
            null, //nullColumnHack
            values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values
}
```

Thanks for your reading time, I would be really grateful if someone had any idea.

EDIT : Stacktrace :

```
07-08 12:01:57.755: D/addPerson(10828): Person [sid=9290, attended=, serial=92906,    time=2014-04-07 18:44:59, title=Miss, forename=Ladina, lastname=Clement, parking=,    numberpeople=2, accessreqornot=No, accessreq=, timetable=Fine]
07-08 12:01:57.755: D/addPerson(10828): Person [sid=9291, attended=, serial=92907, time=2014-04-08 18:44:59, title=Miss, forename=Ladina2, lastname=Clement2, parking=, numberpeople=2, accessreqornot=No, accessreq=, timetable=Fine]
07-08 12:01:57.763: D/addPerson(10828): Person [sid=9292, attended=, serial=92908, time=2014-04-07 18:44:59, title=Miss, forename=Ladina3, lastname=Clement3, parking=, numberpeople=2, accessreqornot=No, accessreq=, timetable=Fine]
07-08 12:01:59.193: D/ViewRootImpl(10828): ViewRoot  TouchDown(Absolute) DOWN (357 , 189)
07-08 12:01:59.247: D/getAllPersons()(10828): []
```

Comment: Do you have checked if there is some data stored? After inserting something.

Comment: Although not aware of the complexity of your program, an easier way would be [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: I can't really check if there is some data stored. I agree it would be the easiest way, but I'm working on a non-rooted device, so I can't access my db. I saw that we can with a virtual device, but I need an external app and external files, so it's really difficult for me to work with it.

Comment: You just copy your DB from the internal folder -- you dont need a rooted device. Check for a [better explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093458/copy-database-file-to-sdcard-in-android)

Comment: The empty fields like parking=, look suspicious to me. Try filling them up.

Comment: You should print the output of your `db.insert(TABLE_PERSONS...` call as the return code tells you "the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred"

Comment: I tried to export my DB with the link you have sent Byzantine Failure, thanks a lot by the way. Sadly, I don't find the output DB file on SD card like it should be. I will post a link to my full project, it will be easier to understand and fix in my opinion.

Comment: Here is my project : http://www.speedyshare.com/Fpvk2/Project.zip
In it you have the android project and the CSV. The project uses OI File manager to select the csv file. So :
1- Put csv in the device
2- Install OI file manager on the device
3- launch app

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: I tried what you said dave.c, thank you for your answer, and I got the right id ! So it seems that the insert is ok. I'm really lost right now ^^'

Comment: @Byzantine Failure I made the DB export work, I had just a little bug. My DB is actually empty, and my field SID is in integer instead of long like I asked in the code. Weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
}
```

to

```
if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // do something when there are no results
}
```

The null check on the cursor is redundant. You can check if the cursor is empty by doing cursor.moveToFirst(). If it returns false you should prevent executing further commands on the cursor like you are doing later e.g. cursor.getString(0).

Comment: Why not use an else condition? (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())?

Comment: @ByzantineFailure no need to check for null cursor. And why use else condition and enclose a massive code block when you can call return if there are no query results.

Comment: I am not sure about the performance effects, but it would be interesting to research about this. WIll update and keep posted here.

Comment: I tried to change it, and the "something when there are no results" is not triggered, so it has to be something else.

Answer (score 1):

My data is like this:

```
25-07-14 12:00,15,52,16,50,42,58,63,62,52
22-06-14 14:00,15,52,16,50,42,58,63,62,52
12-09-14 19:00,45,51,16,50,42,58,13,34,52
02-02-14 16:00,15,52,16,50,42,58,63,62,52
01-05-14 12:00,15,52,16,50,42,58,63,62,52
```

i have read that data like this you can find once. In the file path i am checking is that csv file are not.

```
FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                if(FilePath.substring(FilePath.length()-4).endsWith(".csv"))
```

And the code is here

```
 private void readcsvfile() {

    if(FilePath.length()>4)
    {
    dataGridTable = new DgaDataGridTable(context);
    equipmentTable = new EquipmentTable(context);

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FilePath)));

        String line;

        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) 
        {
            info = new DgaDataGridInfo();
            String[] rowData = line.split(",");

            if(rowData[0].length()!=0&&rowData[1].length()!=0&&rowData[2].length()!=0&&rowData[3].length()!=0&&rowData[4].length()!=0&&rowData[5].length()!=0&&rowData[6].length()!=0&&rowData[7].length()!=0&&rowData[8].length()!=0&&rowData[9].length()!=0)
            {
                info.setDateadded(rowData[0]);
                info.setH2(Integer.parseInt(rowData[1]));
                info.setCh4(Integer.parseInt(rowData[2]));
                info.setC2h2(Integer.parseInt(rowData[3]));
                info.setC2h4(Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]));
                info.setC2h6(Integer.parseInt(rowData[5]));
                info.setCo(Integer.parseInt(rowData[6]));
                info.setCo2(Integer.parseInt(rowData[7]));
                info.setO2(Integer.parseInt(rowData[8]));
                info.setN2(Integer.parseInt(rowData[9]));
                info.setTdcg(Integer.parseInt(rowData[1])+Integer.parseInt(rowData[2])+Integer.parseInt(rowData[5])+Integer.parseInt(rowData[4])+Integer.parseInt(rowData[3])+Integer.parseInt(rowData[6]));
                equipmentname = equipment_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                info.setEquipid(equipmentTable.getEquipmentId(equipmentname));

                dataGridTable.insertRecord(info);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Dga Records Succesfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loadAllDgaRecords();

            }
            else
            {
                showAlertDialog();
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please choose csv file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Thanks