# Android How can I see my SQLite?

Tags: java, android

I used Eclipse to open `data/data/your.package.name/databases`,but there's nothing in `data`.

Some people say I didn't get the "root privileges".

How can I see my SQLite?

Comment: you can use sqlite browser to see the database of your app ....

Comment: The database browser don't know where is it?I must tell him the path.

Comment: You need to get your android device rooted.Check out on google there are number of links regarding the same,however for the time being why not trying on the emulator which already have all the root previliges and you can access the db file from **DDMS** and then file explorer.Pull it from the device,save on your hard drive and use **[Sqlite query browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)** to view the db file

Comment: yes you should extract the file and follow the procedure as @nobalG told you to do so ...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, I think, to write a small function in your app, which copies the `/data/.../etc` to the `/sdcard/`, or somewhere else.

After that, you'll be able, to open that DB from your computer.

Here's a full answer, how to copy the file into the SDCard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19093736/2891426

I would implement this function in a whole new class, and create a button, which calls this. Or something like this.

And you can download a small Windows app from here, to browse the DB file: http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: I know the database path.But I can't open it or even can't found it.

Comment: Are you sure, that there is a DB.? You trying to reach it from your app? You cannot read that storage from anywhere else (android do not let to read those files any other app!), if you don't root your phone, but only from your app!

Answer (score 0):

You do need root access to see the databases on your device. You can use an emulator though, instead of the physical device, and that will allow you to explore the databases in Eclipse.

Comment: How can I get 'root privileges'?

Comment: @chunhao2107: it depends on your phone, version, etc. I would suggest you the xda-dev's forums, that's a good resource in phone stuff. BUT, if you root your phone, you'll probably lose your warrianty, and you'll be able to do some very uncool stuff. SO root your phone only, if you know what are you doing!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to have root privileges to access external storage. you need for internal storage though. in eclipse in ddms go to android/data/yourpackage and there you should find all files created by your app. if there is no file, then there is no database.
once you find your database you can use sqliteman to see its content
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteman/files

best solution would be to use internal storage and then just export it to external when you want to access it. look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19093736/2026478

```
public void exportDatabse(String databaseName) {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+databaseName+"";
            String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use SQLiteBrowser For That You can Easily Access Your Database.
You Can Download from here http://sqlitebrowser.org/