# how to view Android DB with intelliJ?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I hace created a new Android DB with tow tables.

How can I view their content using intelliJ or sqliteBrowser app?

I cannot find my apk database on the device.

how can i locate it easily?

I have tried to follow this

but I don't know how to config the path to my DB (nor I know its path)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You app is installed in the device (ie you already executed your app in that device)?

Comment: yes. but I cannot find its folder nor its db

Comment: You can copy it to your sdcard and then open it in a browser database.Like that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093458/copy-database-file-to-sdcard-in-android)