# How to export and import database sqlite in android studio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, export

I am trying to implement an export and import in my android app, I have tried the below for export but it isn't working and doesn't give any errors. Could someone please help me out.

```
public static void export() throws IOException {
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    String inFileName = "/data/data/com.example.main/databases/myDB";
    File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

    String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myDB";
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

and I call the method like so:

```
try {
    export();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? and also once exported how can I import the data back?

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it isn't working" means.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly isn't working, the data isn't getting exported. I export() method in a button click so when I press a button nothing is happening. If I had Log.d in the method that isn't brought up either.

Comment: Where did you get that code from? Do you understand it? Do you get a stack trace in the log?

Comment: I get no stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure that is that how you would export a database? Can you check that the file that you are reading with `FileInputStream` can be exported that way? In my mind you would need someway of communicating with SQL to ask for this.

Comment: I am relatively new to Android and SQLite itself. To my understanding, the file should already be saved in the specified path, and it's the case of copying it from there to a new directory. I am not really sure. In essence what I really want is allow users to export the database to their local storage as a backup and provide a import function to import that in. I am not really sure how to go about doing it though.

Comment: "If I had Log.d in the method that isn't brought up either" -- then step through your code in a debugger.

Comment: Can I ask, is here a default location where android saved a database created by app?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that what you require is answered here... it worked for me..

[copy database file to sdcard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093458/copy-database-file-to-sdcard-in-android)

Note: This isn't intended to be a lazy answer, simply, I know this works so hopefully it will help the poster!

Comment: That isn't working either, I know both codes are right, could something else be wrong potentially? I am calling the method write but not sure if they are being executed as logs are not printing, could you maybe give me pointers as to how you got it to work please?

Comment: Hi Adam,

For me, I created a static function within a specific Utilities class and then made a call to it. What I did additionally was to ensure the manifest contained android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Is there any chance that you missed that out?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I have declared the permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Adam, have you tried to step through the code whilst it runs? I'm wondering if your paths etc... are all correct as the app steps through the above code?

Comment: I am fairly new to android, would you be able to tell me how to step through a code please? I know my inFileName directory is correct as I have been through it using the command. I am not sure how else to access my database as the adnroid monitor does not show my phone.

Comment: Assuming that you are using Android Studio... go to the section of code that deals with storing your database.... (the stuff that you've posted above).  Click on the left-hand side of the code window (to the right of the line numbers) to set a break point. 

Run your code in debug mode and it should hit the breakpoint.

Step over code as appropriate and examine that values... that should help you see what is actually being done.

Comment: I will give that a go, may I ask would it be difficult to export to and import from google drive instead of sd card?

Comment: Hi Adam, I shouldn't think it would be, however, it seems to me like you're not too familiar with Android or Android Studio as yet so, I'd hold back on that unless it's imperative! Good luck :)

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to do that please, I might as well offer users that instead of saving to an SD card. Well not neccessrily google drive but gives users the option to where to save e.g., when they click the export button to bring up a dialog with email, google drive, sky drive, internal memory etc. and allow them to click on it to save there. That way I can see if it is working or not as well. As currently when I press export it doesn't save to SD card.