# Android: Cursor is always returning null

Tags: android, cursor

i'm trying to pass information into Fragment where i send the name of the user Stored inside my table. however its always returning empty which let me suspicious of the place of the Cursor .

i looked into sample solutions online and couldn't solve it. here what i did so far:

```
public DbResponse getData(){
    DbResponse obj = new DbResponse();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);


    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor!= null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
        // i want the name of the user here
        obj.Dname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_1));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return obj;
}
```

Also i have a class where its

```
public class DbResponse {
public String Dname;
```

}

and Finally i'm trying to cast it Here:

```
    public void ShowData(){
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    DbResponse response = db.getData();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.Dname , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Toast always return nothing which i font know Why. 
Please Advice. Thank YOU

Comment: Change your line :  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: Did Change it still Toasting nothing. Any suggestions

Comment: Have you added any read write permission in mainfest ?@Ahmad Meer

Comment: I did not, however i added this    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and its still empty

Comment: first check there is data in table,import database to sdcard and check using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093458/copy-database-file-to-sdcard-in-android

Comment: so you dont have any data in your table

Comment: will i wrote an insertion method that store data and return if its successfully or not. Alongside a checking method And I added new info just to make sure its not empty

Comment: if cursor is null then it get crash at  cursor.moveToFirst(); because you have added it before checking cursor is  null or not

Comment: what you see when you call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` method?

Comment: im not familiar with  DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor can you explain please

Comment: what to explain? just call that method and watch the logcat, so what do you see?

Comment: Sorry took me a while, Debguning is my weakness. Here is the result V/Cursor Object: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@81fc4a0

Comment: and then you have: `<<<<<` ? so it means the cursor is empty, no data in your table

Comment: for testing you can add some data using [sqlite3](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html) tool

Comment: True. ok doesnt this line add to the database        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("Name", Name);

Comment: without `db.insert()`? no

Comment: Sadly i have the insert method, I have no idea where to look now

Comment: Ok narrowing it down now. After hours of searching I found that I’m unable to find any database when using android monitor using API 25, or my physical phone. but here is the surprise I used API 23 and it worked perfectly. Any idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your code properly & database also, as your database is created or not? whether it contains table and does table have values?

Let me know for any queries!

Comment: Ok narrowing it down now. After hours of searching I found that I’m unable to find any database when using android monitor using API 25, or my physical phone. but here is the surprise I used API 23 and it worked perfectly. Any idea how to fix it.

Comment: You will not be able to find database for you physical device or phone. You can get database for avd or simulator device.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Finally Made IT. I can’t really explain my Answer with greater Details because I’m still intermediate in coding but:

I found out that none of the Functions in Database Helper is being called from the fragment’s so No insertion or Anything happening.
So, I thought perhaps it has to do with (onAttach or Activity or Context) not beaning sent.

Now I don’t know exactly what they do if someone can explain it easily its much appreciated.
I sent all the information collected from the Fragment to the main activity where it had Fragment Listener implemented. And then the main activity executed the DB function.
And it Worked :P